# Kibana shows indices that don't exist in elastic

Tags: kibana, openshift-origin

I've deployed a logging stack as [described here](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/aggregate_logging.html), with ops-cluster option enabled. Now I have an issue that both kibana and kibana-ops show the same set of indices that include .operations.* and project.* logs but elastic that is bound to kibana-ops doesn't have project.* indices and vice verse for elastic that is bound to kibana. 
If I navigate to an index that shouldn't be there (for example project.* index in kibana-ops) I'll get `No results found`, `Shard Failures` and search indicator that never stops. If I delete index on the Settings tab it'll get recreated after a few seconds.

I'm confused where does kibana get indices from and how to make it show only appropriate ones. Any help?